# Replace an axiom of propositional calculus formal system P.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

We construct a new propositional calculus formal system $P'$. Different from $P$, axiom (A3) is changed to:
$$(\neg\alpha\rightarrow\neg\beta)\rightarrow((\neg\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow\alpha)$$
Prove that the set of internal theorems of $P'$ and $P$ are identical.

Note: Axioms of $P$

(A$1$) - $(\alpha\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow\alpha))$

(A$2$) - $((\alpha\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow\gamma))\rightarrow((\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\gamma)))$

(A$3$) - $(((\neg\alpha)\rightarrow(\neg\beta))\rightarrow(\beta\rightarrow\alpha))$

I've understood that if we mark the new axiom as (A4), we just need to prove that (A3) could be derived directly from (A1), (A2) and (A4). But I've tried different combinations and failed.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Bram28 I've edited the question about my thoughts just now.

Comment: Very good. Yes, you'll want to derive A3 from A1, A2, and A4. But to prove equivalence between these two sets, you'll also need to derive A4 from A1, A2, and A3.  If you can use the fact that A1, A2, and A3 forms a complete set of axioms, and given that A4 is a logical truth, then that second half is trivial.  But yes, you'll need to derive A3 from A1, A2, and A4.  Can you use the Deduction Theorem?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, we can use the deduction theorem. Because the proof of the deduction theorem is just based on (A1) and (A2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can show that you can derive $A3$ from $A1$, $A2$, and $A4$.

As you yourself note, given $A1$ and $A2$, we can prove the Deduction Theorem for this system. So given that, let's try to show that for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we can derive $\alpha$ from $\neg \alpha \to \neg \beta$ and $\beta$:

$1. \neg \alpha \to \neg \beta$

$2. \beta$

$3. \beta \to (\neg \alpha \to \beta) \ (\text{by } A1)$

$4. \neg \alpha \to \beta \ (\text{MP } 2,3)$

$5. (\neg\alpha\rightarrow\neg\beta)\rightarrow((\neg\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow\alpha)  (A4)$

$6. (\neg\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow\alpha \ (\text{MP } 1,5)$

$7. \alpha \ (\text{MP } 4,6)$

OK, so we have shown that $\neg \alpha \to \neg \beta,  \beta \vdash \alpha$

By the Deduction Theorem, this means that $\neg \alpha \to \neg \beta \vdash  \beta \to \alpha$

And thus by the Deduction Theorem again, we have $\vdash (\neg \alpha \to \neg \beta) \to ( \beta \to \alpha)$